# Error unresolved token (06000001) LNK2020 in Visual c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, c++-cli, visual-studio-2013

Hi I keep getting this error message when I create a new class:

```
error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) write_functions::WritePaths
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The class .h file looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

ref class write_functions
{
public:

private:

   std::pair<bool,std::string> WritePaths(System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox^ Box);
};
```

I have made other classes that look similar to this,  they work just fine so I don't know why I get this error all of a sudden.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What does your .cpp file look like? If this is somewhat similar to standard C++ then it means you have not defined the method anywhere or did not include the corresponding object file into your project.

Comment: Looks like an accurate linker error, I don't see the *implementation* of the WritePaths() function either.

Comment: Please create a [small example](http://sscce.org/) and post it here.

Comment: Added C++/CLI and Winforms tags since this code is C++/CLI and referencing `Forms`.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi so you take out winforms tag but leave in user-interface?

Comment: @crashmstr I only added c++-cli. Maybe my change got reviewed after yours so that removed winforms unintentionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `WritePaths` has not been implemented. I don't see anything wrong with the declaration, but if you declare the method and don't actually implement it, this is the linker error you should get. If you do have an implementation in your .cpp file, please post it.

Comment: OK I got it too work after implementing WritePaths in the .cpp file, i found the error strange seance i have declared stuff in .h files before and not put them in the .cpp file and not gotten the error.


Thank you @reirab your answer it helped!!

Comment: @Sailordi You might not get the error if the method is nowhere called actually. Or maybe you declared it inline like `int foo(int bar) {return 0;}` in the .h file.